# Sitecore disable user event

Tags: user-management

Does anyone know is it possible to subscribe to an event about disable user throw sitecore user management .

it is  a lot of events in sitecore about it, but user:updated event not raised if a user was disabled.

```
Event.Subscribe("user:deleted", this.OnUserDeleted);
    Event.Subscribe("user:deleted:remote", this.OnUserDeleted);
    Event.Subscribe("user:updated", this.OnUserUpdated);
    Event.Subscribe("user:updated:remote", this.OnUserUpdatedRemote);
    Event.Subscribe("user:runtimerolesupdated", this.OnRuntimeRolesUpdated);
    Event.Subscribe("user:runtimerolesupdated:remote", this.OnRuntimeRolesUpdatedRemote);
```

Comment: Following Sitecore code, it should work. On clicking disable user button UpdateUser method is executed. 

Do you have custom Membership provider? Can you add membership section from web.config file to question?

Comment: And switchingProviders section from Sitecore.config?